# Explicit expression of closest integers in the proof that $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \sqrt {2} \right]$ is euclidean.

Tags: ring-theory, integers, euclidean-domain

**Context : proof with an explicit expression of "closest integers" that $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \sqrt {2} \right]$ is euclidean.**

When i draw a two dimensional network in the example of $\mathbb{Z} \left[ i\sqrt {2} \right]$ i find that , given $x+i\sqrt{2} y$ where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2
$ , we can find a closest element with compounds "x and y" integers given explicitely by :
$$a=\lfloor x+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor,b =\lfloor \sqrt{2}y+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\rfloor $$
(In the sense, $a+i\sqrt{2}b\in \mathbb{Z} \left[ i\sqrt {2} \right]$ and is the closest to $x+i\sqrt{2}y$ for conventional norm on $\mathbb{C}$).

If that's correct.

But in the case of $\mathbb{Z} \left[ \sqrt {2} \right]$ , i can't really find the explicit expression given $x+\sqrt{2} y$ where $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2
$ of the closest element with integer compounds "x and y", i can't make a proper draw.

**What's the proper explicit expression , and how to see it on a draw that seems to be one dimensional**

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual metric. In particular, given $\xi \in \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and $r > 0$, the set $(\xi - r, \xi + r) \cap \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ is infinite.

Comment: @LázaroAlbuquerque this answer was definitely welcome !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such closest element. For example, the diophantine equation

$$(2x-1)^2-2(2y)^2=1$$

has infinitely many solutions in positive integers $x,y$ and the corresponding elements $x-y\sqrt{2}\in \mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ tend to $\frac 12$ from the right. This means that there is no element of $\mathbb Z[\sqrt 2]$ closest to $\frac 12$ in the usual metric on the reals.